# N dimensional space search algorithms

Tags: algorithm, neural-network, statistics

I have an input N dimensional space. I also have a function f which given some point in the space, would return how likely this point is a "good" point [some measure between [0, 1]]. I know that "good" points are often close together in the space. But there could be clusters of these good points spread across the entire search space. So there could be regions which are excellent in producing these good points.

What are some good approximate algorithms / statistics / techniques I could apply to get as many of these points as possible, and also as extensive as possible (covering as many cluster as possible).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the topics of [cluster analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis) and [statistical classification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_classification).

The point here is that there are many different algorithms and it really depends a lot on your application and the structure of your input data if a certain method is appropriate.

You might want to use a [data mining tool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_mining#Software) for evaluating different algorithms on your specific data. I have used *RapidMiner* in the past to do so and learned a lot about what worked well for my application and what did not.